# toChanglelogStream prints different kinds of changes

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I am reading at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/#examples-for-fromchangelogstream,

The EXAMPLE 1:

```
// === EXAMPLE 1 ===

// interpret the stream as a retract stream

// create a changelog DataStream
val dataStream = env.fromElements(
    Row.ofKind(RowKind.INSERT, "Alice", Int.box(12)),
    Row.ofKind(RowKind.INSERT, "Bob", Int.box(5)),
    Row.ofKind(RowKind.UPDATE_BEFORE, "Alice", Int.box(12)),
    Row.ofKind(RowKind.UPDATE_AFTER, "Alice", Int.box(100))
)(Types.ROW(Types.STRING, Types.INT))


// interpret the DataStream as a Table
val table = tableEnv.fromChangelogStream(dataStream)

// register the table under a name and perform an aggregation
tableEnv.createTemporaryView("InputTable", table)
tableEnv
    .executeSql("SELECT f0 AS name, SUM(f1) AS score FROM InputTable GROUP BY f0")
    .print()

// prints:
// +----+--------------------------------+-------------+
// | op |                           name |       score |
// +----+--------------------------------+-------------+
// | +I |                            Bob |           5 |
// | +I |                          Alice |          12 |
// | -D |                          Alice |          12 |
// | +I |                          Alice |         100 |
// +----+--------------------------------+-------------+
```

The EXAMPLE 2:

```
// === EXAMPLE 2 ===

// convert to DataStream in the simplest and most general way possible (no event-time)

val simpleTable = tableEnv
    .fromValues(row("Alice", 12), row("Alice", 2), row("Bob", 12))
    .as("name", "score")
    .groupBy($"name")
    .select($"name", $"score".sum())

tableEnv
    .toChangelogStream(simpleTable)
    .executeAndCollect()
    .foreach(println)

// prints:
// +I[Bob, 12]
// +I[Alice, 12]
// -U[Alice, 12]
// +U[Alice, 14]
```

For the two examples, I would ask why the first one prints `-D` and `+I` in the last two records, while the second one prints `-U` and `+U`. What's the rule here to determine the kind of change? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference has two parts, both of them defined in `GroupAggFunction`, which is the process function used to process this query.

The first is this part of the code:

```java
// update aggregate result and set to the newRow
if (isAccumulateMsg(input)) {
    // accumulate input
    function.accumulate(input);
} else {
    // retract input
    function.retract(input);
}
```

When a new value is received for a given key, the method first checks if it is an accumulation message (`RowKind.INSERT` or `RowKind.UPDATE_AFTER`) or a retract message (`RowKind.UPDATE_BEFORE`).

In your first example, you explicitly state the `RowKind` yourself. When the execution reaches `Row.ofKind(RowKind.UPDATE_BEFORE, "Alice", Int.box(12))`, which is a retraction message, it will first retract the input from the existing accumulator. This means that after the retraction, we end up with a key which has an empty accumulator. When that happens, the below line is reached:

```java
} else {
    // we retracted the last record for this key
    // sent out a delete message
    if (!firstRow) {
        // prepare delete message for previous row
        resultRow.replace(currentKey, prevAggValue).setRowKind(RowKind.DELETE);
        out.collect(resultRow);
    }
    // and clear all state
    accState.clear();
    // cleanup dataview under current key
    function.cleanup();
}
```

Since this is not the first row received for the key "Alice", we emit a delete message for the previous row, and then the next one will emit an `INSERT`.

For your second example where you don't explicitly specify the `RowKind`, all messages are received with `RowKind.INSERT` by default. This means that now we don't retract the existing accumulator, and the following code path is taken:

```java
if (!recordCounter.recordCountIsZero(accumulators)) {
    // we aggregated at least one record for this key

    // update the state
    accState.update(accumulators);

    // if this was not the first row and we have to emit retractions
    if (!firstRow) {
        if (stateRetentionTime <= 0 && equaliser.equals(prevAggValue, newAggValue)) {
            // newRow is the same as before and state cleaning is not enabled.
            // We do not emit retraction and acc message.
            // If state cleaning is enabled, we have to emit messages to prevent too early
            // state eviction of downstream operators.
            return;
        } else {
            // retract previous result
            if (generateUpdateBefore) {
                // prepare UPDATE_BEFORE message for previous row
                resultRow
                        .replace(currentKey, prevAggValue)
                        .setRowKind(RowKind.UPDATE_BEFORE);
                out.collect(resultRow);
            }
            // prepare UPDATE_AFTER message for new row
            resultRow.replace(currentKey, newAggValue).setRowKind(RowKind.UPDATE_AFTER);
        }
```

Since the row count is greater than 0 (we didn't retract), and this is not the first row received for the key, and because the `AggFunction` has set `generateUpdateBefore` to `true`, we first receive an `UPDATE_BEFORE` message (`-U`) followed immediately by an `UPDATE_AFTER` (`+U`).

All the relevant code [can be found here.](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/6a537343ad71f28ba47b25f30a6a5872d5b1044f/flink-table/flink-table-runtime-blink/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/operators/aggregate/GroupAggFunction.java)

Comment: Thanks @yuval-itzchakov for the great answer,it really helps.